# Delete a child node

Tags: javascript, dom, svg

I am trying to delete the string attribute here, but I guess I don't have reference to the child node.
How should this work?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var attrs = document.getElementById('test-1');
        attrs.removeAttribute('string');
    </script>
    <mask>
        <mpath>
            <font-face-format string="" id="test-1"></font-face-format>
       </mpath>  
    </mask>
</svg>
```

Comment: An HTML5 doctype is not appropriate for an SVG document.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to reference it when it still doesn't exist.

try moving your script block to the end of the document like

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">    
    <mask>
        <mpath>
            <font-face-format string="" id="test-1"></font-face-format>
        </mpath>  
    </mask>
    <script type="text/ecmascript">
       var attrs = document.getElementById('test-1');
       attrs.removeAttribute('string');
    </script>
</svg>
```

Comment: I gave you +1, but now I have to -1 because you have put the `<script>` outside of the `<svg>`. Move it back inside and you'll get a +1 again. Also, note that the proper mime type for `<script>` inside of SVG is either to omit the attribute, or use `text/ecmascript`. :)

Comment: The Doctype doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: i was just focusing on the problem in hand, i didn't check the whole code

Answer (score 2):

make use of `window.onload` so that the code will executed once the element is created. try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function(){
        var attrs = document.getElementById('test-1');
        attrs.removeAttribute('string');
 };
</script>
```

Comment: …because, as noted by @André, your `<font-face>` element does not yet exist when you call `getElementById()`. You have to wait until the document is loaded.

Comment: Wouldn't `DOMContentLoaded` be better?